# Not able to load divs one below the other using Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, bootstrap-5

I am trying to order `div's` one under the other and want it centered on the page but all my elements are lining next to each other rather than one below the other.

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b7fb98327c.js"></script>

<div class="landing d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100" id="start">
    <div id="start-app">
      <p id="app-name" class="header h1">App Name</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email" class="form-label">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div>
      <label for="pwd" class="form-label">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play" id="start-icon"></i></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want the `divs` to line one under the other. Right now they are all forming next to each other. `<br>` does not seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `flex-column` added as a Class. You can read more here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#direction

(I removed the `height: 100vh` as the content wouldn't fit otherwise)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b7fb98327c.js"></script>

<div class="landing d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100 flex-column" id="start">
    <div id="start-app">
      <p id="app-name" class="header h1">App Name</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email" class="form-label">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div>
      <label for="pwd" class="form-label">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play" id="start-icon"></i></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```